# unable to color faces using indexedfaceSet in x3dom

Tags: html, google-chrome, xhtml, x3dom

I am looking for a way to display some meshes with color mapping in Chrome browser, so I have tried `x3dom` and `indexedFaceSet`. I assume there is a way to assign colors to vertices so that the color of the face is interpolated or at least I should be able to assign different constant color to each face. It seems that no matter what I try, I can only display lines of the faces and defined colors have no effect.
Currently, I have this html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.js'> </script> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.css'></link>
</head>

<body>
    <X3D width='600px' height='400px' showLog='true'>
        <Scene>
            <Shape>
                <IndexedFaceSet coordIndex='0 1 2 -1, 1 2 3 -1' colorPerVertex='true' solid='false'>
                    <Coordinate point='0 0 0, 1 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0'/>
                    <Color color='0 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 1, 0 1 0'/>
                </IndexedFaceSet>
            </Shape>
        </Scene>
    </X3D>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose, I am either missing something very simple or x3dom does not work properly on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is in using **.xhtml** format (rather than **.html**) with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='x3dom.css'/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <X3D width='600px' height='526px'>
      <Scene>
        <Transform>
          <Shape>
            <IndexedFaceSet solid='false' coordIndex='0 1 2 -1'>
              <Coordinate point='1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 3'/>
              <Color color='1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1'/>
            </IndexedFaceSet>
          </Shape>
        </Transform>
      </Scene>
    </X3D>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This solution was created reducing [this example](http://examples.x3dom.org/example/x3dom_paraviewExport.xhtml) to a "minimum example" of what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively. As Tomas said, we have to use **.xhtml** format rather than **.html** .
See below with my answer, an example of how to draw a pyramid with *IndexedFaceSet* using field *colorIndex* and *color*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://www.x3dom.org/download/x3dom.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='x3dom.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<X3D width='50%' height='50%'>
<Scene>
<Shape>
<Appearance><Material specularColor='1 1 1' shininess='0.9' /></Appearance>
<IndexedFaceSet solid='false' creaseAngle='0.000' colorPerVertex='false' coordIndex='0 1 2 -1 0 1 3 -1 0 2 3 -1 1 2 3 -1' colorIndex='0 1 0 2' >
<Coordinate point='1 0 0  0 1 0  0 0 1  0 0 0 ' />
<Color color='1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1.' />
</IndexedFaceSet>
</Shape>
</Scene>
</X3D>
</body>
</html>
```