# Error while rendering volume data with x3dom

Tags: x3dom

I tried to set up the same volume renderer as in the official [demo](https://examples.x3dom.org/volren/volrenOpacityTestTF_aorta.xhtml). Unfortunately, I always get the error `Cannot read property 'textures' of null`. I created a simple JSFiddle to [demonstrate the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/ke9czexa/).
How do I make the volume show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple problem: You have been using the XHTML syntax. JSFiddle needs the HTML syntax. I have fixed this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vhzhLmvx/):

```
<X3D xmlns='http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-namespace' showStat='true' showLog='false' width='500px' height='500px'>
  <Scene>
    <Background skyColor='0.0 0.0 0.0'>
    </Background>
    <VolumeData id='volume' dimensions='4.0 4.0 4.0'>
      <ImageTextureAtlas containerField='voxels' url='https://examples.x3dom.org/volren/aorta4096.png' numberOfSlices='96' slicesOverX='10' slicesOverY='10'>
      </ImageTextureAtlas>
      <OpacityMapVolumeStyle lightFactor='1.2' opacityFactor='6.0'>
      <ImageTexture containerField='transferFunction' url='https://examples.x3dom.org/volren/transfer.png'></ImageTexture>
      </OpacityMapVolumeStyle>
    </VolumeData>
  </Scene>
</X3D>
```

I think it was documented in the past, but nowadays I only found the [simple examples](https://examples.x3dom.org/simpleExamples.html) where there are different examples for HTML and XHTML respectively.

A similar answer can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201556/698496